# Android - AAR file causes errors

Tags: android, android-library, aar, aapt, manifest-merging

I build an aar file. It use some dependency. build.gradle file of my libray:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

My aar file path -> `app/libs/mylibrary.aar`

I edit top level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Add the library as a dependency

```
implementation(name:"mylibrary", ext:"aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

My application id: my.sample.app

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
>   /SampleApp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-21:19 Warning:
>           application@android:label was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:6 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>   /SampleApp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-21:19 Warning:
>           application@android:icon was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:6 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>   /user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/eb66b88fff0dbb2e75f036f5373b5bbf/res/layout/activity_btb.xml:10: AAPT: error: attribute 'my.sample.app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' not found.

I add dependencies that used by library, the error is gone.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation(name:"mylibrary", ext:"aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

But this is not best way. How can I fix this error? Why my library couldn't find its dependecies.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason of this error.

> The aar file doesn't contain the nested (or transitive) dependencies
>   and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by
>   the library.
>
> It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a flatDir repo
>   you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.
>
> You should use a maven repository (you have to publish the library in
>   a private or public maven repo), you will not have the same issue. In
>   this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which
>   will contains the dependencies list.

Original answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36475009/4319615